# Getting odd results from a for loop inside a filter function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, filtering

I'm looping inside a filter. I want to get the values from my `vals` array plus the keys(name, description) for my filter.

When I iterate through my `vals` array, I keep getting returned the `name` but not the key.

Ideally I would like the return method to give me key and value.

`return x[this.searchValues[i]].includes('phil')`

to be
`return x.name.includes('phil')`
   `return x.decription.includes('phil')`

```
  const vals = ['name', 'decription']

  const arr =[{
    name: 'joe',
    decription: 'is a guy who likes beer'
   },
   name: 'phil',
    decription: 'is a super hero'
   }]

  this.result = arr.filter((x) => {
    for(let i = 0; i< vals.length; i++){
       return x[this.searchValues[i]].includes('phil');
    }
  })
```

Comment: Could you give an example output, as your description is a bit confusing.  `I keep getting returned the name and not both.`  a filter will return the whole record, so not sure what your saying here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const vals = ['name', 'decription']

const arr =[{
  name: 'joe',
  decription: 'is a guy who likes beer'
 },{
 name: 'phil',
  decription: 'is a super hero'
 }]

 let result = arr.filter(e => vals.some(n => e[n].includes('phil')))
 
 console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, you need to clearly state what is your goal in the question.

But if the goal is to get an object with name 'phil' from arr, then this could be done like this:

```
this.result = arr.filter(x => x.name === 'phil')
```

if you need to get objects where any property equals 'phil' then:

```
this.result = arr.filter(x => Object.keys(x).every(k => k === 'phil'))
```

Comment: `every`, did you mean `some`,  `every` is going to get objects where all properties contain phil.

Comment: obviously my solution has to be altered - the requirements are not completely clear